# does Intersystem ODBC driver have a max record processing

Tags: crystal-reports, odbc, report

After the Crystal report runs 9,204,903 records at the tail end of the report I get records that come up as corrupted. There are special characters (&*#%) in fields that are numeric or string and also Chineses characters. Wanted to know if this is a known issue that the ODBC driver has a max processing records or a possible fix is known for this. 
Any help is appreciate. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not yet downloaded the latest ODBC driver, then start there. My understanding is that all latest versions of the Intersystems ODBC drivers are backwards compatible to prior versions.

ODBC Drivers are located here:

ftp://ftp.intersystems.com/pub/cache/odbc